# How to automatically get the current date and time in a column using HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

Hey I have two columns in my HIVE table :

For example :-

```
c1 : name
c2 : age
```

Now while creating a table I want to declare two more columns which automatically give me the current date and time when the row is loaded.
 eg:  `John  24  26/08/2015 11:15`
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i found a way to do it using shell script.

Heres how :

echo "***$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%T")*** $(wc -l /home/hive/landing/$line ) $dir " >> /home/hive/recon/fileinfo.txt

Here i get the date without spaces. In the end I upload the textfile to my hive table.

Answer (score 1):

Hive currently does not support the feature to add a default value to any column definition while creating a table. Please refer to the link for complete hive create table syntax:
[Hive Create Table specification](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable) 


Alternative work around for this issue would be to temporarily load data into temporary table and use the **insert overwrite table** statement to add the current date and time into the main table.


Below example may help:


**1. Create a temporary table**

```
create table EmpInfoTmp(name string, age int);
```

**2. Insert data using a file or existing table into the EmpInfoTmp table:**

> ***name|age*** 
>  Alan|28
>  Sue|32
>  Martha|26

**3. Create a table which will contain your final data:**

```
create table EmpInfo(name string, age tinyint, createDate string, createTime string);
```

**4. Insert data from the temporary table and with that also add the columns with default value as current date and time:**

```
insert overwrite table empinfo select name, age, FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'dd/MM/YYYY' ), FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'HH:mm' ) from empinfofromfile;
```

**5. End result would be like this:**

> **name|age|createdate|createtime**
>  Alan|28|26/08/2015|03:56
>  Martha|26|26/08/2015|03:56
>  Sue|32|26/08/2015|03:56

Please note that the creation date and time values will be entered accurately by adding the data to your final table as and when it comes into the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You can't set more then 1 column as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Here this way, You cant set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in one column

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hive` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `datecreated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, how can i do it through the terminal?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, BUT yoy can refer this link http://www.intechgrity.com/automatically-insert-current-date-and/#

Comment: The question is about HIVE which uses HiveQL language, your answer is only works for MySql